# A fishing pole for lake and ocean fishing

Tags: fishing, sea

I'm looking for a fishing pole that can work for fishing trips to the ocean as well as lake fishing. I fish a lot in New Jersey (surf, bay, boat) and also visit lake Winnipesaukee quite a bit. Is there something that would work for both? I haven't purchased a new pole in years.

Comment: Presumably you are looking for a spinning rod and not fly fishing or baitcasting.

Comment: @JonEricson thanks for the response! Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @ChristinaRule - Disclaimer. I am a noob. I'd suggest that you look into telescopic surf rods of heavy and medium heavy action. The caveat is that most dealers in USA do not stock/sell such rods. You'll have to either pay 2-3x cost of rod for shipping from outside USA.

Answer (score 4):

Much depends on what you are fishing for and how you are fishing for it. I was an avid freshwater angler for almost forty years before my wife and I moved to Florida, and I have the garage full of tackle to prove it.

What I found when I got here is that my lightest freshwater combos were too light for most saltwater fishing. Probably the most practical combo I have now is a 7 foot medium-heavy spinning rod with a 400-class spinning reel. I use it for everything from panfish along the beach to snapper fishing in the gulf.

I have another rig for heavier fishing, like reef fishing for grouper. It's a 5' 6" boat rod coupled with a Penn Senator reel.

Given enough line capacity and lack of obstructions and snags, you can land surprisingly large fish on light tackle. My best to date is a ~28# barracuda caught on what the charter boat's mate called the "Snoopy rod". It was a light action freshwater rod meant for bass, walleye and panfish in fresh water.

Comment: Yep, a heavy spinning rod will suit for most situations.  It is somewhat limiting in lakes, and somewhat limiting in surf.